# JWT doesn't get stored in ASP.NET Core with Blazor

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, jwt, blazor

I followed this tutorial: https://medium.com/@st.mas29/microsoft-blazor-web-api-with-jwt-authentication-part-1-f33a44abab9d

I downloaded the example: https://github.com/StuwiiDev/DotnetCoreJwtAuthentication/tree/Part2

I can see that the token is created but I don't understand how it is or should be saved on the client side as each time I access the `SampleDataController`, which has the `Authorize` tag, it returns a 401.

When calling and adding the token using Postman it works.

What am I missing for my user to be authenticated? Doesn't `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer` handle the client part (storing the token)?

Comment: Are you using `Authorize` as the name in the headers?  If so, it should be `Authorization`.

Comment: That's the part I don't understand. I followed the tutorial and downloaded the project and expected to see token after doing the login. How should this token be set? JwtBearer doesn't do it for me I assume according to your comment?

Comment: I understand your confusion...the tutorial doesn't appear to be using the `Authorization` header but is providing the token as a query string parameter.  The author shows how to use it in Postman for testing but not in the client app.  He mentions at the end of Part 2 that you can save the token to localStorage but doesn't give an example of actually making a request from client to server using the token.  It's not a very good or helpful tutorial IMO.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> What am I missing for my user to be authenticated? Doesn't Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer handle the client part (storing the token)?

The `JwtBearer` runs on server side , it will only validate the authorization header of request, namely `Authorization: Bearer your_access_token`, and won't care about how you WebAssembly codes runs . So you need send the request with a jwt accessToken . Since the tutorial suggests you should use `localStorage` , let's store the `accessToken` with `localStorage` .

Because `WebAssembly` has no access to `BOM` yet, we need some javascript codes served as glue . To do that, add a `helper.js` under the `JwtAuthentication.Client/wwwroot/js/` :

```
var wasmHelper = {};

wasmHelper.ACCESS_TOKEN_KEY ="__access_token__";

wasmHelper.saveAccessToken = function (tokenStr) {
    localStorage.setItem(wasmHelper.ACCESS_TOKEN_KEY,tokenStr);
};

wasmHelper.getAccessToken = function () {
    return localStorage.getItem(wasmHelper.ACCESS_TOKEN_KEY);
};
```

And reference the script in your `JwtAuthentication.Client/wwwroot/index.html`

```
<body>
    <app>Loading...</app>
    <script src="js/helper.js"></script>
    <script src="_framework/blazor.webassembly.js"></script>
</body>
```

Now, let's wrap the javascript codes into C# . Create a new file `Client/Services/TokenService.cs`:

```
public class TokenService
{
    public Task SaveAccessToken(string accessToken) {
        return JSRuntime.Current.InvokeAsync<object>("wasmHelper.saveAccessToken",accessToken);
    }
    public Task<string> GetAccessToken() {
        return JSRuntime.Current.InvokeAsync<string>("wasmHelper.getAccessToken");
    }
}
```

Register this service by :

```
// file: Startup.cs 
services.AddSingleton<TokenService>(myTokenService);
```

And now we can inject the `TokenService`  into `Login.cshtml` and use it to save token :

```
@using JwtAuthentication.Client.Services
// ...
@page "/login"
// ...
@inject TokenService tokenService

// ...

@functions {
    public string Email { get; set; } = "";
    public string Password { get; set; } = "";
    public string Token { get; set; } = "";


    /// <summary>
    /// response from server
    /// </summary>
    private class TokenResponse{
        public string Token;
    }

    private async Task SubmitForm()
    {
        var vm = new TokenViewModel
        {
            Email = Email,
            Password = Password
        };

        var response = await Http.PostJsonAsync<TokenResponse>("http://localhost:57778/api/Token", vm);
        await tokenService.SaveAccessToken(response.Token);
    }
}
```

Let's say you want to send data within `FetchData.cshtml`

```
@functions {
    WeatherForecast[] forecasts;


    protected override async Task OnInitAsync()
    {
        var token = await tokenService.GetAccessToken();
        Http.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization",String.Format("Bearer {0} ",token));
        forecasts = await Http.GetJsonAsync<WeatherForecast[]>("api/SampleData/WeatherForecasts");
    }
}
```

and the result will be :

[image]

Comment: Thanks for an awesome explanation, now it works!
Just for the record: To be able to inject the `TokenService` I needed to add it to service in `Startup.ConfigureServices - services.AddSingleton<TokenService>(myTokenService);`

Comment: Excellent answer, really useful. Also, really useful comment above. I'd recommend putting it in the answer as without it the tokenservice can't be called.

Comment: @GeorgeHarnwell Thanks for your suggestion, I've edited my answer :)

Answer (score 3):

Apologies in advance as this is somewhat responding to a previous answer, but I don't have the rep to comment on that.

If it helps anyone else who was similarly looking for a solution to using JWT in a Blazor app, I found @itminus answer incredibly useful, but it also pointed me to another course.

One problem I found was that calling `FetchData.cshtml` a second time would blow up when it tries to add the `Authorization` header a second time.

Instead of adding the default header there, I added it to the HttpClient singleton after a successful login (which I believe Blazor creates for you automatically).  So changing `SubmitForm` in `Login.cshtml` from @itminus' answer.

```
    protected async Task SubmitForm()
    {
        // Remove any existing Authorization headers
        Http.DefaultRequestHeaders.Remove("Authorization");

        TokenViewModel vm = new TokenViewModel()
        {
            Email = Email,
            Password = Password
        };

        TokenResponse response = await Http.PostJsonAsync<TokenResponse>("api/Token/Login", vm);

        // Now add the token to the Http singleton
        Http.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", string.Format("Bearer {0} ", response.Token));
    }
```

Then I realised, than as I'm building a SPA, so I didn't need to persist the token across requests at all - it's just in attached to the HttpClient.

Answer (score 2):

The following class handle the login process on the client, storing the JWT token in `local` storage. Note: It is the developer responsibility to store the JWT token, and passes it to the server. The client (Blazor, Angular, etc.) does not do that for him automatically.

```
public class SignInManager
    {
        // Receive 'http' instance from DI
        private readonly HttpClient http;
        public SignInManager(HttpClient http)
        {
            this.http = http;
        }

        [Inject]
        protected LocalStorage localStorage;


        public bool IsAuthenticated()
        {
            var token = localStorage.GetItem<string>("token");

            return (token != null); 
        }

        public string getToken()
        {
            return localStorage.GetItem<string>("token");
        }

        public void Clear()
        {
            localStorage.Clear();
        }


        // model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: false
        public async Task<bool> PasswordSignInAsync(LoginViewModel model)
        {
            SearchInProgress = true;
            NotifyStateChanged();

            var result = await http.PostJsonAsync<Object>("/api/Account", model);

            if (result)// result.Succeeded
           {
              _logger.LogInformation("User logged in.");

              // Save the JWT token in the LocalStorage
              // https://github.com/BlazorExtensions/Storage
              await localStorage.SetItem<Object>("token", result);


              // Returns true to indicate the user has been logged in and the JWT token 
              // is saved on the user browser
             return true;

           }

        }
    }
```

// This is how you call your Web API, sending it the JWT token for    // the current user

```
public async Task<IList<Profile>> GetProfiles()
        {   
            SearchInProgress = true;
            NotifyStateChanged();

            var token = signInManager.getToken();
            if (token == null) {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(AppState)); //"No token";
            }

            this.http.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);

            // .set('Content-Type', 'application/json')
            // this.http.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);

            Profiles = await this.http.GetJsonAsync<Profile[]>("/api/Profiles");


            SearchInProgress = false;
            NotifyStateChanged();
        }
```

// You also have to set the Startup class on the client as follows:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // Add Blazor.Extensions.Storage
       // Both SessionStorage and LocalStorage are registered
       // https://github.com/BlazorExtensions/Storage
       **services.AddStorage();**

      ...
    }
```

// Generally speaking this is what you've got to do on the client. // On the server, you've got to have a method, say in the Account controller, whose function is to generate the JWT token, you've to configure the JWT middleware, to annotate your controllers with the necessary attribute, as for instance:

```
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
```

and so on...

Hope this helps...